# Samsung S7 can't access mobile networks

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, mobile-network, samsung-galaxy-s7

This is my father's phone and he went overseas to travel. During his travel he wanted to unlock his phone so he went to some shady area and they apparently rooted his phone but messed up somewhere. They told him to reinstall the firmware and it will be good. Unfortunately that isn't the solution and I have no clue what is the problem.

The mobile networks always has the cross symbol and no option for it exists in the settings. This prevented me from accessing the APN settings, but then after searching for that I managed to get access to it. However, it won't let me create any new APN and there exists none other, giving me the error that this user cannot change the APN settings. No number could be dialed and gives another error that there are no mobile networks. Removing the SIM and trying another SIM does nothing at all.

I then got a firmware from sammobile with the same network as the phone, Koodo 6.0.1 and installed that. The problem still persists and I have run out of ideas and solutions on what to do. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the IMEI still present (Settings->Device Information->Status->IMEI Information)? If it's all 0's, you may be out of luck because it's a good indicator for a removed `/efs` partition (unique to each device, holds information like IMEI and other important stuff).

Comment: Yes, that information is "unknown". How can I proceed from here? I do have the IMEI number if there was a way to put it back in.

Comment: Try flashing with Odin and this time go to Options and check Phone EFS Clear. This should recreate the EFS partition

Comment: Should I bother to backup the EFS before attempting this in case anything goes wrong? I was going to root the phone, backup the EFS and then try to clear the EFS.

Comment: It's a good idea but for now it's pointless, since your EFS is corrupted anyway. Recreating EFS as suggested above using Odin is a good move. Anyway it doesn't hurt to take back up

Comment: So, I tried clearing the EFS in Odin and let it reboot. Unfortunately the problem still exists.